# Remove duplicates chars recursively

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function which remove all duplicate chars from a given string recursively.
For example "Hello world" -> "Helo wrd".

The limitations I have are:

1. No loops allowed.
2. No more arguments can be added to the original function (remove_duplicates).
3. No functions from string.h library allowed, although I'm allowed to write them recursively.

I'm allowed to use another auxiliary recursive functions.

The function I wrote so far works only for short strings, it calls the function too many times. Any recommendations how to make it more efficient?

```
void remove_duplicates3(char string[], int index)//(str,RecursiveStrlen(str, 0)-1)
{
    int length = RecursiveStrlen(string + 1, 0);
    if (string[index] == '\0' || index == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (string[0] != string[index])
    {
        remove_duplicates3(string, index - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        BackspaceString(string, index);
        remove_duplicates3(string, length - 1);
    }

    remove_duplicates3(string + 1, length - 1);
}

int RecursiveStrlen(char str[], int index)
{
    if (str[index] == '\0') 
        return index;
    return RecursiveStrlen(str, index + 1);
}


void BackspaceString(char string[],int index)//deletes one char from string in a specific index
{
    if (string[index] == '\0')//end of string
        return;
    string[index] = string[index + 1];
    BackspaceString(string, index + 1);
}
```

Comment: Side question: do you have a limitation on the length of the string? Because using recursion can turn sour if done too many times.

Comment: Yes, the limitation is 256 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure recursive solution:

```
void remove_char(char string[], char c, int read_index, int write_index) {
    if (string[read_index] == 0) {
        string[write_index] = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (c == string[read_index]) {
        remove_char(string, c, read_index + 1, write_index);
    } else {
        string[write_index] = string[read_index];
        remove_char(string, c, read_index + 1, write_index + 1);
    }
}

void remove_duplicates(char string[], int index) {
    if (string[index] != 0 && string[index + 1] != 0) {
        remove_char(string, string[index], index + 1, index + 1);
        remove_duplicates(string, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a global variable to store the resultant string, you could do this:

```
char result[30]="";
char over[30]="";


int check(char *over, char c)
{
    if(*over != '\0')
    {
        if(*over == c)
        {
            return 1; //exists
        }
        else
        {
            return check(over+1, c);
        }
    }
    return 0; //doesn't exist
}

int strLen(char *str)
{
    if(*str=='\0')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return strLen(str+1)+1;
}

void remove_duplicates(char *str)
{
    if(*str != '\0')
    {
        if(check(over, *str)==0)
        {
            int len=strLen(result);
            result[len++]=*str;
            result[len]='\0';

            len=strLen(over);
            over[len++]=*str;
            over[len]='\0';
        }
        remove_duplicates(str+1);
    }
}
```

The resultant string is stored in `result` and `over` is a string which will store the already encountered characters as a string. `over` is checked by the `check()` function against a character `c` to return `0` if `c` was not found in `over`.

`check()` checks the value of `over` to determine if its argument `c` is present in `over`.

`remove_duplicates()` will check each character in the input string `str`. If the character was not encountered before in `str`, it is added to the list of already encountered characters to `over` and also appended to the `result` string.

This goes on till the input string `str` is over.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is having only ASCII characters -

```
int arr[256] = {0};

/*
 * str - Input string
 * presult - Pointer to the buffer contain result
 */
void remove_duplicates(char *str, char *presult)
{
    if(*str != '\0')
    {
        if(arr[*str] == 0)
        {
            *presult = *str;
            arr[*str] = 1;
            remove_duplicates(str+1, presult+1);
        }
        remove_duplicates(str+1, presult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Recursive Solution

I originally wrote this function in Scheme, but have translated it into C for you.

```
/*
 * @params
 * src  ->  input string from which to remove duplicates
 * dest ->  output string (initially empty)
 * iter ->  elements visited (initially 0)
 */
void remove_Dups_recursively(char *src, char *dest, int iter){

    if(strlen(src) <= 1){
      dest = src;
      return;
    }

    if(iter == strlen(src)){
        return;
    }


   if(strchr(dest, src[iter]) == NULL){
       dest[strlen(dest)] = src[iter]; 
       iter++;
       remov(src, dest, iter);
   }

   else{
       iter++;
       remov(src, dest, iter);
   }
}
```